Package file not copied to the output, and not available to the analyzer
I have a library that contains some APIs and analyzers as well. The API is relying on an Ulid package. There are consumer libraries to the API library, and those are validated, they also rely on this library. The consumers (for now) have project references for the API+analyzer library project, plus such an entry:
<Analyzer Include="..\..\artifacts\bin\integration\debug\apilibrary.dll" />

The analyzer is shown in the tree with the red "ignored" dot - but as far as I know, that's not an issue. The diagnostic IDs are also visible.
The consumers all have:
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="Ulid" Version="1.3.4" />
</ItemGroup>

The library is showing up in the dependency tree. The code compiles, the Ulid struct is usable, no problem there. But the validator fails:

warning AD0001: Analyzer 'ApplicableOnConstraintAnalyzer' threw an
exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' with message
'Could not load file or assembly 'Ulid, Version=1.3.4.0,
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5635ede1d450abf5' or one of its
dependencies.

I have checked in the output folder for the consumer libraries. None have the ulid.dll there. The API library has it.
Why isn't the dll not copied? But even if I copy the dll manually in the output folder, the analyzer errors persist.
I have followed the isntructions from here: https://www.meziantou.net/packaging-a-roslyn-analyzer-with-nuget-dependencies.htm, but for now this is not a nuget package, just a local project in the solution.
What am I missing?
[Update 2024-09-03]
I have introduced some hack to find the location where the analyzer us running from. The location is like this: C:\Users\zolta\AppData\Local\Temp\VBCSCompiler\AnalyzerAssemblyLoader\31795ec204b648a39746e18e0eefde7b\7a517bbf-e323-4e18-a9c4-1b0111412a39\apilibrary.dll. I have inspected the folder, and the libraries I use in the project are not there, just my library. Is there any setting to force this or any workaround?
I have created a demonstration repository: https://github.com/zorgoz/AnalyzerSatelliteLibraryIssue
